# How to interpret Autoencoder anomoly SE for one hot encoded variables?

Tags: r, h2o, autoencoder

Here is some reproducible code. I want to know what the calculation is for the SE on a per feature basis when the features are one-hot encoded. If I'm to give it my own attempt:

It looks like some of the SEs are 1, which I guess would mean that the reconstruction was 100% sure it was one thing but it was actually the other. For the fractional errors, do they represent various degrees of wrongness with respect to the probability assigned to the category from the softmax classifier?

```
library(h2o)
art <- data.frame(a = c("a","b","a","c","d","e","g","f","a"),
              b = c("b","c","d","e","b","c","d","e","b"),
              c = c(4,3,2,5,6,1,2,3,5))

dl = h2o.deeplearning(x = c("a","b","c"), training_frame = as.h2o(art),
                      autoencoder = TRUE,
                      reproducible = T,
                      seed = 1234,
                      hidden = c(1), epochs = 1)
sus.anon = h2o.anomaly(dl, as.h2o(art), per_feature=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about h2o autoencoder but it seems to me that autoencoder do not work correctly with one-hot encoded variables.  I tried everything. What I didn't try is the 'Categorical variational autoencoder using the Gumbel-Softmax estimator' (https://github.com/ericjang/gumbel-softmax).